SQLServerAgent could not be started (reason: Unable to connect to server ‘------’; SQLServerAgent cannot start)
Firstable I would like to mention about this question.
I saw many post in Google about this incident but seems that every solution does not help me and that's why I make this question here.
So here is the incident:
Background:  I have a IAAS VM with SQL Server(2022 Standard) installed on Azure platform, a week ago, a coworker maded a snapshot of the disks and decommisioned the VM. So he moved those snapshots to another VM and started the VM. After that when I connected to the VM. I figure out that the SQL Server were corrupted and also the letters of disks were different.
I changed the path of the system database and the SQL Services went online and working fine.
Incident:SQL Agent can not start afther several attempts. I tried to change the parameters of 'Alias local host server' but the error keep going.
Example documentation: https://sqlsheeshya.wordpress.com/2022/11/10/sqlserveragent-could-not-be-started-reason-unable-to-connect-to-server-xxxxxx-sqlserveragent-cannot-start/
Also I tried to change the value directly on Regedit but the same behavior after trying to enable the service.
Example documentation:https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/sql-server-agent-cant-start
https://vox.veritas.com/discussions/enterprise-vault/unable-to-connect-to-server-local-sqlserveragent-cannot-start/271861
Neither of those solution worked for me. So now I running out of ideas.
Also I changed and tried the three options from 'Built-in account' but nothing happens.
In the logs or event viewer I can only see the same error message about not being able to connect to the server but nothing else.
Best regards

You're in Azure.  There's no reason to try to "fix" this server.

Create a new, healthy SQL Server VM
Attach the old disks
Copy the databases to the default database location of the new server
Attach the databases.

